# grant permissions to multiple database users in one line

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following line in my stored procedures to grant permissions to a user for this stored procedure

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[GetItem] TO [<<DBUSER>>]
```

The stored procedure is consolidated in to one big script with others using Powershell where I replace the <> value with a user name.

I would like to modify this so that I can grant permissions to an user in a list that exists in that database. For example:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[GetItem] TO [User1, User2, User3]
```

Is it possible with SQL, to do this? I am trying to minimize the changes as much as possible. If the user does not exist in the database, it just ignores it.

Comment: Have you considered having a group for users who can use the stored procedure and giving the group execute permissions?  Then you can just add users into the group.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx) for `GRANT`, you can indeed do this. But because of the [brackets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx), your query is trying to grant permission to *one* user called `[User1, User2, User3]`. You probably want this:

`GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[GetItem] TO [User1], [User2], [User3]`

Although as Gordon pointed out, a group would be much easier in this case if possible.

Comment: Thanks for this - if the user does not exist, will it throw an error?